# what dows TTIsPad() do in Xcode using Three20?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i'm using Three20 in XCode but i copied a piece of code like this:

```
if (TTIsPad()) {
    SplitCatalogController* controller =
        (SplitCatalogController*)[[TTNavigator navigator] viewControllerForURL:@"tt://catalog"];

    SplitCatalogController* controller =
        (SplitCatalogController*)[[TTNavigator navigator] viewControllerForURL:@"tt://catalog"];
    TTDASSERT([controller isKindOfClass:[SplitCatalogController class]]);
    map = controller.rightNavigator.URLMap;
}
```

But i don't know what does the function TTIsPad do, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It is a convenience method that returns true if the current device is an iPad, and false otherwise.

The source can be found [here](https://github.com/vauto/three20/blob/master/src/Three20UICommon/Sources/TTGlobalUICommon.m).  It first checks whether the device is running iOS 3.2 or greater.  If not, it returns false (iPads shipped with 3.2)  If it is greater than 3.2, it returns the result of (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) which is true only if the device is an iPad.